# how to disable trace & redirect to https at same time using mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a RHEL4 server with apache 2.0.52. I want to disable trace method and redirect all http requests to https both at the same time in one virtualhost. I have done foll.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]
```

Both the rewrite rule work independently. But when put together, trace method is not disabled. The output of trace via telnet is

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 02 Nov 2009 01:34:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat)
Location: https://192.168.0.174/error/noindex.html
Content-Length: 304
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://192.168.0.174/error/noindex.html">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat) Server at 192.168.0.174 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: You didn't show what your combined attempt looks like-- van you do that?

Comment: Sorry, I dint understand what you mean by 'combined attempt'. The output of trace command above, happens when I use both the rules together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recollect how I figured out but the foll. rewrite rules work. The sequence is - first the https redirection rule should be present and then the trace disable rule should be present. Also I removed the L present in https redirection rule, since it is the first rule. So finally the rewrite rules look like :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply an `[L]` last flag to your first rule if you wish the request to stop there.

If you wish to disable `TRACE` requests completely (server wide) then you might want to use the [`TraceEnable`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#traceenable) directive instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use mod_rewrite for this at all. There's a simple directive for allowing or denying the HTTP method TRACE: [TraceEnable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#traceenable).

Comment: TraceEnable is only supported from apache version 2.0.55.